# Решение на PHP для фотогалереи сайта

Tags: php, javascript

Не знаю, как написать фотогалерею для сайта на PHP. Нужно, чтобы из админки можно было добавлять новые изображения. На странице они должны выходить в виде миниатюр и при нажатии увеличиваться. Подскажите, готовые решения.

Заранее благодарен, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[Фотогалерея](http://www.softtime.ru/info/photo.php).

И я все понимаю, но этот форум создан по-моему для частных вопросов, потому такие вопросы как этот или "нужен сайт, чтобы была админка, еще новости, игры и т.д. и т.п." должны удаляться администрацией без каких-либо объяснений.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Коллеги, я думаю, в данном случае имеет место недоразумение, этот вопрос по сути спрашивает о рекомендации к использованию: автор просто не совсем верно выразил свою мысль. То есть это не вопрос вида «сделайте мне сайт», а вопрос вида «посоветуйте компонент». Такой вопрос, не являясь вопросом программирования, отчасти относится к администрированию и допустим на сайте.

Comment: Если человек правильно формулирует то, что хочет спросить - то и получает нужные ему ответы.

В данном вопросе я вижу слово "Решение ...", что уже наталкивает на мысль о каком-то готовом варианте, т.е. вопрос не интересен. Если бы человек задал бы вопрос Гуглу или Яндексу, то нашел бы больше ссылок и примеров с картинками, чем здесь ему могли бы подсказать.

Comment: Не согласен. Задавая вопрос человек ждет точного ответа от людей, которые уже попробовали, тем самым экономя большое количество времени. Зайдя в гугл, он видит много решений, которые надо скачать, попробовать, дать критическую оценку.

Comment: ЗаGooglлив этот вопрос, появится куча сайтов с готовым текстом, в которых надо долго ковыряться чтобы поставить, разбираться, и по большей степени эти тексты не являются быстрыми, и уж однозначно не подходят по дизайну сайтов.
Я в общем то сам хочу сделать что то подобное, но не знаю с чего начать.
Готовые тексты я использовать не хочу, хочу разучить все сам.
Далее читайте мой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Используй "[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)". А вообще согласен с "Alex Silaev" - вопрос неуместен для этого ресурса.

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом я хотел бы посоветовать в этом вопросе добавить метку javascript, так ты быстрее найдешь ответ на свой вопрос, поскольку для данного эффекта целесообразно использовать именно этот язык программирования.
При помощи функции javascript:

```
function openWin90{
myWin=open("bla.php")
}
```

можно открыть новое окно в браузере, где будет открываться любой документ, например увеличенная картинка.
Но я не считаю, что это самый лучший способ добиться хорошего результата, и в javascript я не селен, но все таки, лучше чем нечего.

Comment: Быстрый способ отображать большие варианты изображений - это jquery&lightbox (гуглить по слову lightbox).

Можно написать самому, например добавив слой div на страницу и грузить туда изображение, отображая слой при клике на тумбнейлы. Все, что нужно от админки - это добавление и удаление фотографий, что сделать абсолютно не сложно даже тем, кто немного знает php, даже просто на файлах, без БД. Так что все в Ваших руках.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать любой бесплатный движок интернет-магазина, в позициях добавлять только фотографии. Те же самые миниатюры - отображение каталога, и увеличенный вид - при клике - помогут полторы строки на jQuery (это).

А вообще согласен с Alex Silaev, насчет php и базы на файлах)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы автору [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) посоветовал. Из всех, что я когда-либо видел, самый удачный, красивый и кроссбраузерные вариант. Легко поддается настройке. Сам использую на своем сайте. Можете посмотреть пример: [mrkfish.ru/photogallery](http://mrkfish.ru/photogallery)